# MS BotBuilder (Node SDK) : How to display a list within a Card?

Tags: botframework

I'm displaying a card in which the text section has 3 bullet points that are supposed to be shown in a list.

```
let content = {
                'title' : 'Title',
                'text' : "1. Sentence for first point \n\n 2. Sentence for second point \n\n 3. Sentence for third point"
            }

let card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title(content.title)
                .text(contents.text);
            let msg = new builder.Message(session).attachments([card]);
            session.endDialog(msg);
```

On the Webchat the text is displayed as a paragraph with no line breaks.

How do I insert line breaks here? Or is there any other way to show a list?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1439

Comment: What channel are you using? Some channels support markdown style message formatting but not all.  It will depend on your targeted channel.

Comment: @NilsW Im using Directline-Webchat

Answer (score 0):

```
  card = HeroCard(
        title="some titles'",
        subtitle='subtitle',
        text="Sentence for first point, Sentence for second point,Sentence for third poin",
        images=[CardImage(url="https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png")],
        buttons=[])
```

for bullet list

'text' : "- Sentence for first point \r- Sentence for second point \r- . Sentence for third point\r"

---

for numbered list

'text' : "1. Sentence for first point \r2. Sentence for second point \r"

---

for bold

example: some text **what is text want to bold** some other text

---

for italic

example: some text *text* some other text